Can we use React Hooks inside JSX component's callback like this?
Does this count as breaking the rule of hooks? It doesn't show the error/warning 'Error: Invalid hook call' and the code works normally. useEffect also mounts only once

1.✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
2.✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.
3. Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.
4. Do not call Hooks after a conditional return statement.
5. Do not call Hooks in event handlers.
6. Do not call Hooks in class components.
7. Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.
https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning


we technically call the hook in the top level of the HookContainer component
not a custom hook. if we see useHooks as custom hook, it is still in top level
no condition/loop in HookContainer. if HookContainer is in .map or && conditions, the hooks is still init when HookContainer is mount. I think it is still similar to regular component with hook inside since the useHook in HookContainer is init inside the component
it is not called after a conditional return statement
From the example, it's more like a onClick / on* props.
-
-

If it does break the rule of hooks, what's the drawback of using it this way? It would be great if there's a counter example of why this case it an anti-pattern. Thank you very much!
Here's the playground: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/goofy-mcclintock-pchv3f
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  console.log("rerender");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <HookContainer
        useHooks={() => {
          const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

          useEffect(() => {
            console.log("HookContainer mount");
          }, []);

          return {
            counter,
            setCounter,
          };
        }}
      >
        {({ counter, setCounter }) => (
          <div>
            <p>counter: {counter}</p>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
              }}
            >
              increment
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </HookContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

type HookContainerProps<T> = {
  children: (props: T) => JSX.Element;
  useHooks: () => T;
};

const HookContainer = <T extends object>(props: HookContainerProps<T>) => {
  const hookData = props.useHooks();

  const Element = props.children;

  return <Element {...hookData} />;
};

export default App;

------ New Section ---------
Seems like this way also works. The state is also still in order (according to Robin Zigmon comment)
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const arr = Array.from({ length: 3 })

export function App(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} />
      {name && arr.map((_, index) => <ComponentWrapper key={index}>
        {() => {
          const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
          useEffect(() => { console.log('init') }, [])
          return <div>
            <p>{counter}</p>
            <button onClick={() => { setCounter(prev => prev + 1) }}>increment</button></div>
        }}
      </ComponentWrapper>)}

    </div>
  );
}


const ComponentWrapper = (props) => {
  return props.children()
}


This 100% breaks the Rules of Hooks. It's not an "anti-pattern" so much as it would make any hooks in called in your component fail to work properly, so React will make your component fail with this error. As to why - the React docs used to have the explanation, but I can't seem to find it there now, maybe it got removed which is unhelpful imo. But it's still in the "legacy docs" here

if you don't mind, could you give me an example where "React will make your component fail with this error"?

I assume you meant "React relies on the order in which Hooks are called". correct me if I'm wrong but isn't this way, all the hooks are still in order? (no skipping)

Yes exactly, the key is indeed that "React relies on the order in which Hooks are called". So how often will the HookContainer component call that useHooks function prop? Maybe it always calls it according to the "rules of hooks", but there's no way of telling without seeing the implementation of that component (which you don't show us), and this means React can't possibly guarantee that either.

Oh now I notice that you do give the implementation. I'd not seen that before. I now see that what you are doing probably is OK, although I expect any linter will have an issue with your use of useState inside the function prop.

IIUC, this is simply an extra abstraction layer around a custom Hook, that provides props for a Function-as-a-Child, and works without breaking any rule:

the callback you pass to useHooks is a custom Hook function
that custom Hook is called at the top level inside <HookContainer> Component (as you already realized in your point 2)

While this abstraction may look strange, I do not see technical issues with it, except for the Function-as-a-Child (FaaC) render prop which is instantiated as a Component (<Element/>), whereas it should just be called as a simple function ({Element(hookData)}): because the callback you pass as FaaC is inlined, it is a new function at each render, hence React destroys and re-creates its DOM nodes everytime, instead of re-using them (to avoid browser re-layout and re-paint, which is the whole point of React Virtual DOM). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78743482/5108796 and https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component (for the reverse reason: keep the inlined FaaC as a "JSX sub-template", in the same context as the <HookContainer> Component, instead of rendering it as a new Component at each render). Or you could memoize it.

I have updated the component. can I have your comment/review again? thank you

The FaaC is now indeed called instead of instantiated; the custom Hook is now directly inlined within that FaaC (I find it better than your previous version, as it removes a verbose artificial separation, no more arguments coupled to the Hook return). The only advantage I see in this unconventional abstraction, is to avoid having to name that Component: it "hides" behind a <ComponentWrapper>.

BTW as pointed out by RobinZigmond in the question comments, linters will very probably trip in this unconventional architecture (even if it technically works, much like a Hook after an if(true) works but fires up linters). So if at any point you want your code to be auditable, this for sure will be a red flag.
